# Optimizing with microdata and address tag

Tags: html, html5, microdata

Can I improve this markup? Is it SEO friendly?

```
<div class="bloc-contenu group" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Hotel" itemref="logo nom-hotel">
 <p><iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d89225.49873817024!2d-74.4423141!3d45.664941!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sfr!2sca!4v1389731001791" width=667 height=325 frameborder=0 style="border:0"></iframe><br>
<small><a itemprop=map href="https://www.google.ca/maps/preview#!q=Brownsburg-Chatham%2C+QC&data=!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x4ccedde9eac0cb83%3A0xf994ff962e761612!3m8!1m3!1d110951!2d-74.4423141!3d45.664941!3m2!1i1920!2i955!4f13.1!4m2!3d45.6608378!4d-74.4472133" target=_blank>Agrandir le plan</a></small>

 <p>Pour réserver ou pour plus d'informations sur nos services&nbsp;:

 <address>
  <p itemprop=telephone>555&nbsp;555-5555
  <p itemprop=address itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress"><span itemprop=streetAddress>38, street name</span>,<br>
  <span itemprop=addressLocality>City</span> (<span itemprop=addressRegion>Province</span>)<br>
  <span itemprop=postalCode>XXXXXX</span>
 </address>

 <p><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target=_blank><strong>Retrouvez-nous sur Facebook</strong></a>
</div>
```

`itemref="logo nom-hotel"` refers to two tags at the top of the page:

```
<img id=logo src="/img/logo.20140104.png" alt="Name of the place" width=161 height=175 itemprop=logo>
```

and:

```
<h1 itemprop=name id=nom-hotel>Name of the place</h1>
```

Comment: [There's a different standard microformat you could use](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard). It's an HTML representation of [this](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6350) and [this](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6351). I don't know why you might prefer this one instead of the schema.org one.

Answer (score 3):

From some research:

- If your code will be used on mobile, I would look into making that phone tag ( which seems to miss `</p>` ) into a functional phone tag : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11143507/7602
- I would imagine you want your facebook link to point to your actual page.
- Your `<p>`aragraphs are not closed properly..
- I would leave `<p>`aragraphs out of `<address>` and would use styled `<span>`s
- `frameborder` is obsolete for `iframe`, while `iframe` should have a `title`
- Your quoting of HTML attributes is inconsistent, in my mind they should all be surrounded with double quotes.

Comment: Thank you for the phone tag link. The Facebook link points to the actual page, I just want to keep it anonymous for now. And I'm ok with unclosed tag in this case. I don't do it in big projects, only in small websites like this. It is W3C valid and there's no bug caused by that. But why would you use `<span>`s instead of `<p>`s in `<address>`?

Comment: Because semantically, those are not paragraphs ( `a distinct section of a *piece of writing*, usually dealing with a single theme and indicated by a new line, indentation, or numbering. ) but pieces of data

Answer (score 0):

Your **Microdata** is fine.

Some **HTML** suggestions:

- I wouldn’t use `p` as container for `iframe` + the map. I’d use `div` instead.
- Don’t use `<br>` after the `iframe` (`br` is [for line breaks that are part of the content](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element) only). Your usage of `br` in the postal address is correct.
- Don’t use `small` for the link to the map (as it doesn’t seem to be a [side comment](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/text-level-semantics.html#the-small-element)).
- You could use [`rel`-`external`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19638774/1591669) for the external links to Google and Facebook.
- You could link the telephone number with the [`tel` URI scheme](http://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc3966). But then you should include the anchor text in a `span` element, as schema.org’s [`telephone` property](http://schema.org/telephone) expects "Text", not "URL" (which would be [the value for the `itemprop` if used on `a`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20889900/1591669)).

  ```
  <a href="tel:555…"><span itemprop=telephone>555 555-5555</span></a>
  ```
- In contrast to what [tomdemuyt answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/39243/16414), using `p` for the postal address seems to be fine (as it’s used in an [example](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element) in the HTML5 spec).